# How to update dialog in Ibm watson Conversation service programmatically

Tags: watson-conversation

I want to update or add Conversation dialog programmatically. is there any way to update or create dialog in Conversation service without editing manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>There is no exposed API yet to automatically upload a JSON file to a workspace.</s>

But you can certainly build your own JSON and manually upload.

---

Watson assistant now has a workspace API that allows you to programmatically build your own workspace. More details on the API page.

https://console.bluemix.net/apidocs/assistant#list-workspaces (See Workspaces -> Dialog Nodes).

Comment: Okay thanks, but is that possible to  edit already created wokspace by uploading json?because when i import json it automatically creates new workspace without updating it.

Comment: There is no functionality to upload to an existing workspace. I have put in an enhancement request for it.